# EF Code First. How to create autoincremented non-index column?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, auto-increment

I use Entity Framework Core. My entity has **[Key] int Id** field, and some other fields. I need to add an autoincremened  **Order** field, that has *previeusEntity.Order + 1* value and has no *unique constraint*. I need this field to implement reordering of displayed entities in UI by swapping values of neighbor columns.

I tried to use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to make autoincremented column, but I don't want it to be part of a key.

How can I make autoincremented field without making it part of a key, and not making it unique? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find elegant solution I wanted, so I just computed value manually for each insertion.